# Retrieving an entry from a column and comparing with other entries from the same column

Tags: mysql

I have a database of employees with salary and names as columns. I want to list all employees who are paid more than a particular person named 'x' from the database itself.

How do I solve this query?

Comment: Please share your query you have tried so far.

Comment: A simple join will suffice

Comment: anything tried so far ?

Comment: @Akansha - did you try my solution? If it worked then please accept the answer and vote up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the salary of the employee 'x' as inner query and check all the records by comparing their salary with x's salary and display them.

```
SELECT * 
FROM employees
WHERE salary > (SELECT salary
        FROM employees
        WHERE name = 'x' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
Select * from Employees where salary > (select salary from Employees where name = 'Katz' );
```

Little Example

[image]